# Virtual Audio Driver on Ubuntu Virtual Machine

Tags: drivers, sound, virtualbox

We are testing a Voice Enabled Program on Ubuntu Virtual Machine. This is a Virtual Machine so there is no actual video or sound card but we need to have Audio and video stream to be flowing through to make the test.We had the same issue with windows VM but we found virtual drivers like Vb Cable etc and made it happen. If any of you have figured out how to do it . can you please share that with me ?